# Entity Framework 7 data annotation support for [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] On a Guid type Primary Key

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an entity base class which I use for the basis of all my entities:

```
    public abstract class EntityBase : IEntity
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }

        set
        {
            if (_id.Equals(default(Guid)))
                _id = value;

            if (_id.Equals(value))
                return;

            throw new InvalidOperationException("Primary Keys cannot be changed.");
        }
    }
    Guid _id = default(Guid);

    [Timestamp]
    public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

However is does not appear that `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`

has any effect.

The Migration created has in the CreateTable method like the following:

```
columns: table => new
            {
                Id = table.Column<Guid>(nullable: false),...
```

this should be:

```
Id = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),...
```

is `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]`
 no longer supported in entity framework 7?  Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` is supported in EF7.

Due to EF7 targets various database providers the way it is stored in migration has changed. Since not all providers support identity columns, there is no `identity` parameter. Instead it is stored as a provider specific annotation. Hence you will see following syntax when a column is going to be used as SQL-Server specific `IDENTITY` column.

```
     Id = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                    .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
```

The semantic meaning of `DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity` is the same as before. Database will generate a value when a new row is added. When targeting SQL-Server, if it is specified on any of the integer type property then EF7 will create Identity column for it. Since `IDENTITY` cannot specified on non-integer or non-numeric types, for any other type there will not be any such annotation. Though the property still has feature that adding a new row will generate a value.

In your example the property is of `Guid` type which translate to `uniqueidentifier` type in SQL-Server. This type cannot be set `IDENTITY` hence there is no annotation found in generated migration. If you try to add a record without specifying value, database will generate a value for you. If you explicitly set value to the property `Id` EF7 will use that value and propagate it to database. That would be expected effect of the annotation.

Comment: This is a slightly disappointing change from EF6.  Is there anyway now to get migrations to set the 'Default Value or Binding' property on the ID column to (newsequentialid())  - The way EF6 used to?

Comment: @John - For property of Guid type with value generation enabled, EF7 generates new values client side using the same algorithm as `newsequentialid()`. So even if the property `Default Value or Binding` is not set, the behavior should remain the same.

If you want to force server to generate values instead of generating them client-side you can use following code in your `OnModelCreating` method:  

`modelBuilder.Entity<EntityBase>().Property(e => e.Id).HasDefaultValueSql("newsequentialid()");`  

This will set `Default Value or Binding` property on server to `newsequentialid()`.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I have already tested this method.  But though the DB was no generating Keys,  I had an issue where on adding an entity to the DB,  The primary key was set by the database, but EF then attempted to change that key with it's own generated key. Causing my entity base to throw the invalid operation exception as seen in the code above.  I've gone back to EF 6 for now,  Ill play with EF7 a  little more before attempting to use it seriously.